# Would filter holders like Lee / Cokin be usable for panning?

Tags: neutral-density, panning

I find that my variable ND isn't all that great in terms of quality (imparts a green tint), so I'm dreaming of replacing them.

I could get a screw on, but then I also like having access to graduated ND.

Are these square filter holders good for handheld panning shots, such as tracking moving vehicles? Or should I stick with screw ons for that application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the filter holder holds the filter snugly, it will be OK. This will be true for most. As to the green tint imposed by your graduated ND: Not good but easy to handle with most any quality photo editing program. If it were me, I would invest in Photoshop. If on a budge then PaintShop Pro. You can download a trial version of PaintShope for free. It's got this feature and much much more.

Comment: The free GIMP ([Gnu Image Manipulation Program](https://www.gimp.org/)) is another option for photo editing...that might be suitable for some people.

Comment: I've used a combination of the Olympus RAW and GIMP to correct for the green tint. GIMP works in a pinch.

The other problem with variable ND is when it's really stopped down, they don't look great (usually with an X pattern from the polarization interference, how these variable NDs are typically built), so I wouldn't mind getting some single pane NDs for my use.

Comment: @Alan_Marcus There's a big difference between a *Variable* neutral density filter and a *Graduated* ND filter.